# Mapping tables to POJOs

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to use JPA to map my java objects to database tables. I know you normally use annotations to map fields to columns. I have a class called Team that has an id (primary key) and name. As far as the class is concerned, id and name are the only attributes that it has. But, in the database, the team table has an id, name, and club_id, since the team is asssociated with a club.

Is there a way I can include a club_id in the insert without explicitly adding club_id as an attribute of the team class?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It sounds like which club the team belongs to is an important part of the domain model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways to do it.

one to many(unidirectional)

in your Club entity you would have

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="club_id", referencedColumnName="club_id")
private List<Team> teams;
```

one to many (bidirectional)

in your club entity

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="club")
private List<Phone> teams;
```

in your team entity

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="club_id")
private Club club;
```

Comment: So I need to add a club as an attribute of the Team?

Comment: It all depends on how you want to access the item.  Should the `Team` know about the `Club` and should the `Club` know about the `Team`?  You might also want a `@OneToMany` on your club relating back to the `Team`.